# How can I perform frame animation with UIView?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have a `UIView` whose frame I am animating, like so:

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 0);

[UIView
 animateWithDuration:0.3
 animations:^{
     view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
 }];
```

The view has an implementation of `layoutSubviews` that does work whenever the size of the view changes. This work cannot be interpolated. What I want is for layoutSubviews to get called for every change of the view's size (when the height is 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.). In practice, however, it gets called for heights 0 and 100, and is then interpolated by the animation system.

Is there any way to get the behavior I'm looking for? I'm open to view animations, layer animations, whatever it takes. I'd like to avoid doing an animation manually with a `timer`, but if that's what it takes....

Comment: You will have to animate the (as stated) special layout yourself - the system is not able to do that for you as soon as interpolation wont do. Have a look at `CAKeyFrameAnimation` (usable e.g. for custom tweening) and `CAAnimationGroup` (used for combined animations).

Comment: Ow, by saying "you have to do it yourself", I certainly am not referring to the use of NSTimer or alike. I am talking about using CoreAnimation.

Comment: @Till I think you're right. I'm still working out the kinks, but I'm using CAKeyframeAnimation now and it is working really well. Thanks!